# static call vs. dynamic call : Which one has better performance?

Tags: php, oop, class

For example this is my class:

```
<?php 
 Class Example
 {
  public function example_function()
  {
   echo "example code";
  }
 }
?>
```

Which one of the following will be best, performance-wise?

1)

```
Example::example_function();
```

2)

```
$example = new Example();
$example->example_function();
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: They are just different, no reason to compare theirs performance (it is pretty close though). Btw, such kind of questions rarely have an answer. To get what is the bottleneck in **your code** - run profiler and see.

Comment: I'm sure in what? It is not the thing that need to be optimized. And static call different to dynamic call by its nature. They are not interchangeable, so no need to compare.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It not a matter of performance. It really isn't. The difference, if there is one, is so minuscule as to be hardly measurable.

If you need to design your class with static methods, use static methods.
If you need to instantiate your class, you have no choice but to use object methods.

It's a class design decision that has nothing to do with performance.

Comment: I wander if there really is a benchmark done to measure the difference. Everyone just keeps saying they are almost the same, but I don't think they are.

Comment: It's trivial to make a benchmark. But it's still pointless. The two do entirely different things and are used for entirely different purposes, so it's really not even a choice. It's trying to compare apples to oranges, so it's moot.

Comment: Take my case as example. I am creating a secure file upload class, and by making the class static I am hoping to gain some performance boost at-least speed-wise. Even if that speed is too minuscule to measure, it is still positive thing, considering a can't gain even that much by makings the class dynamic. So, my question is, the class does not need unit testing, what prevents everyone from using static class instead of dynamic?

Comment: Exactly. If you don't need it, you don't need it. If you do, you do. Static classes are essentially nothing more than functions. If you don't need or want OOP, then don't use it. Performance is entirely secondary.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between the two as far as execution speed is probably insignificant. But they do two very different things.

`Example::example_function();`

is treating the class as a global singleton object. Theres only one Example object, and it might have some public methods that can be called anywhere the class has been included.

```
$example = new Example();
$example->example_function();
```

is creating an instance of the Example class, meaning there can be many Examples running around with different properties.

How you would use these two would depend entirely on the nature of your project and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

If you're planning on accessing class elements, then you need to access the function through an instance of the class. For example, this is not legal when accessed through a static method call (`Example::example()`):

```
class Example
{
    private $str = 'example';

    public function example()
    {
        echo $this->str;
    }
}
```

So, the question isn't about performance, but about *how you're going to use your class and/or functions*.

You should really give the [PHP OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) docs a read.

Comment: You can access class properties from inside static methods.  The properties themselves have to be static as well though.

Comment: Yeah.. I didn't want to get into the details tho (a few too many cases to list that the PHP OOP docs are pretty thorough about ;))

Comment: Your example is perfectly "legal" as long as you instantiate the class. You might want to qualify what exactly is illegal about it...?

Answer (score 2):

As some other comments suggest, It seems the question about performance is secondary. There are other decisions and strategies that will improve your performance, but that one seems more about purely design.

I would suggest it is a question of **good design vs bad design** strategy? And I explain myself.

If you don't need OO, then **why are you using OO?** I mean with that that it seems silly to create objects and then access them as if the would be standard procedural functions.

I was just investigating about that subject, so please feel free to debate against my opinion, I am very happy to receive feedback (positive or negative) about this :-).

Comment: I noticed that, in WordPress plugin development, it is a very common practice using OO as a design rule, indiscriminately. However, after reading an article which, essentially, says exactly what you do (do not use OO if you don't need), I started using static calls in all my plugin codes. Reference: https://stevegrunwell.com/blog/wordpress-plugin-design-patterns/